# Custom post type page display 404 error

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am trying to create a custom post type display page but for some reason the page is not working and I get sent to the 404.php.Here is my code:

```
add_action('init' , 'business_manager_register');

function  business_manager_register(){
    //add custom post type
    $args = array(
        'label' => 'Business Managers',
        'singular_label' => 'Business',
        'public' => true,
        'shouw_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'businesses' , 'with_front' => false)
    );

    register_post_type('businesses' , $args);
}
```

Now in order to display it I have created the file archive-businesses.php.Accoding to the slug I added the link should be something like this:

```
link/businesses
```

But when I try link to it I get the 404 error same thing happenes for the single-businesses.php.What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I've got almostly the same problem, in my case though the archive worked but then has somehow got broken. Well, flushing permalinks helped. I used the 1st way from here: http://wp-bytes.com/function/2013/02/flushing-permalinks/

And while doing that I saw that my permalinks structure was set to "custom". I'changed it to "post title" or how is it called in english.

Answer (score 0):

goto settings->permalinks and use post name so that you can view your post